# How to get values of multidimensional array using a loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multidimensional array:

```
$arr = Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [0] => 1001
                [1] => frank
                [2] => getfrankemail)
            [1] => Array (
                [0] => 1007
                [1] => youi
                [2] => getyouiemail)
            [2] => Array (
                [0] => 1006
                [1] => nashua
                [2] => getnashuaemail)
            );
```

I want to get the values of each array by using a loop or something so I could then put the values into variables such that $aff = 1001, $desc = frank and $camp = getfrankemail and so on...

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is more than one way to do this. Which one did you already try?

Comment: Of course there is a way... See what `for` and `foreach` can do for you.

Comment: Read the docs about loops and arrays. You'll discover that it's full of examples! For example here: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with the variables but that should give you an idea.

```
$arr = Array (
            0 => Array (
                0 => 1001,
                1 => 'frank',
                2 => 'getfrankemail'),
            1 => Array (
                0 => 1007,
                1 => 'youi',
                2 => 'getyouiemail'),
            2 => Array (
                0 => 1006,
                1 => 'nashua',
                2 => 'getnashuaemail')
            );




foreach($arr as $array)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $info)
    {
      echo '<p>'.$key.' => '.$info.'</p>';
    }
}
```

Or

```
foreach($arr as $array)
{
    foreach($array as $info)
    {
      echo '<p>'.$info.'</p>';
    }
}
```

Or

```
foreach($arr as $array)
{
    echo '<p>'.$array[0].'</p>';
}
```

Or

```
foreach($arr[0] as $info)
{
    echo '<p>'.$info.'</p>';
}
```

And more...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested foreach loop (not very efficient or anything, but it gets the job done).

Here's an example:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $nested_arr){
    foreach($nested_arr as $key_2 => $value){
        //Do what you want with the values here. For example put them in 1d arrays.
    }
}
```