# Loop into a multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've got this type of multidimensional array in PHP:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => France
                    [Capital] => Paris
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Italy
                    [Capital] => Rome
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Canada
                    [Capital] => Ottawa
                )

        )

)
```

How can I loop into it ?

I try from my search on documentation:

```
foreach ($countries as $country)
{
  foreach ($country["Name"] as $name)
  {
     $capitals = array();
     foreach ($name["Capital"] as $capitals)
     {
       $capitals[] = $capital["Name"];
     }
     print implode(",", $capitals);
  }
}
```

Desired output should be:

```
Capital of `France` is `Paris`.
Capital of `Italy` is `Rome`.
Capital of `Canada` is `Ottawa`.
```

Could you please point me into the right direction ?

Thanks.

Comment: in your last for each you made mistake. jst var_dump it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Looping through array recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259628/php-looping-through-array-recursive)

Comment: @mickmackusa: updated with the desired output. Thanks.

Comment: @mikeyjk you may retract your dupe link because for this question recursion is overkill.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i get multidimensional array values using foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356768/how-can-i-get-multidimensional-array-values-using-foreach) and [How to get values of multidimensional array using a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018643/how-to-get-values-of-multidimensional-array-using-a-loop) and [How to loop in a multidimensional array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622134/how-to-loop-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use two loops to access the lowest subarray, then you can access the values by their keys (`Name` and `Capital`).

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9ad058c735110cecaaa9a281e178f607fa104501))

```
$array=[
    1=>[
        ['Name'=>'France','Capital'=>'Paris'],
        ['Name'=>'Italy','Capital'=>'Rome']
    ],
    2=>[
        ['Name'=>'Canada','Capital'=>'Ottawa']
    ]
];

foreach($array as $subarray){
    foreach($subarray as $subset){
        echo "Capital of `{$subset['Name']}` is `{$subset['Capital']}`.<br>";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Capital of `France` is `Paris`.
Capital of `Italy` is `Rome`.
Capital of `Canada` is `Ottawa`.
```

Answer (score 0):

just update the foreach loop

```
foreach ($countries as $country)
{
  foreach ($country as $cdata)
  {
     echo "Capital of '".$cdata['Name']."' is '".$cdata['Capital']."'<br/>".
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a late duplicate of my method, therefore it adds no value to the page.

Comment: when i posted your answer was not showing my side. thats why i posted. i didn't mean to post duplicate answer

Comment: That is understandable, but the fact remains that it is a late duplicate.  You should delete it on principle, but I can see that you have received an undermining upvote so now you are less likely to do the right thing.  Thanks Upvote Pixies.